# Noetherian local ring with dualizing complex is quotient ring of a Gorenstein local ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is Noetherian ring with a dualizing complex. [This paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2002-354-01/S0002-9947-01-02817-3/S0002-9947-01-02817-3.pdf) shows that $R$ is a quotient ring of a finite dimensional Gorenstein ring. (Corollary 1.4)

My question is:

> If $R$ is Noetherian local ring with a dualizing complex, then is $R$ a quotient ring of a Gorenstein local ring?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Think about it from the geometry side: saying every Noetherian ring $R$ with a dualizing complex is a quotient of a Gorenstein ring $S$ means that $R=S/I$ for some ideal $I$, or $\operatorname{Spec} R\to\operatorname{Spec} S$ is a closed immersion. If $R$ is local, then the image of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ under this immersion is a closed point $\mathfrak{p}\subset S$, and so the natural map on stalks $S_{\mathfrak{p}} \to R_{\mathfrak{m}}=R$ is again a surjection. But as finite-dimensional and Gorenstein are preserved under taking stalks, we see that $S_\mathfrak{p}$ is finite-dimensional Gorenstein and thus the statement you want is true.

Comment: I asked for local ring. It just said about Noetherian ring which has a dualizing complex is quotient of Gorenstein. II can't see why this is true?

Comment: Ah, I had misinterpreted your question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I don't notice $ R_m=R$ before.